# Графический netstat

Tags: windows

Чем можно смотреть в Windows 7 открытые порты и программы, которые их открыли? Типа netstat, но с графической оболочкой. Замечательный NetView к сожалению разучился делать это в сермерке.

Comment: Вам написать хочется такую программу (тогда Вы угадали форум), но если просто программу хочется - тогда это на руткод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давай [так](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html#DownloadLinks)

Нашёл по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419534/what-is-your-favorite-free-netstat-gui-connection-monitor-app-for-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897437 ?